# What is an intuitive explanation for why if $A,B$ are independent then $A^c, B^c$ are also independent?

Tags: probability, intuition, independence

I know this can be shown using the definition of independence and DeMorgan's law, but I'm wondering if someone can offer an intuitive explanation, with limited to no equations, on why this holds?

Comment: $X$ has the same information as $X^c$, in the sense that if you know $X$ happens, you know $X^c$ did not, and the other way around. So if $B$ does not depend on $A$, how can $B^c$? If $B^c$ does not depend on $A$, how can it depend on $A^c$?

Answer (score 2):

The intuitive notion of independence of two events $A$ and $B$ is that the occurrence of one of them, say $B$, tells you nothing that you didn't already know about whether or not $A$ also occurred, or that $A$ didn't occur. In particular, your belief about the value of $P(A)$ is unchanged by the knowledge that $B$ has occurred, or for that matter, that $B$ has *not* occurred (that is, that $B^c$ had occurred).m Thus, the four statements

1. $A$ and $B$ are independent
2. $A$ and $B^c$ are independent
3. $A^c$ and $B$ are independent
4. $A^c$ and $B^c$ are independent

are *equivalent* statements. If any one of them is true, they are all true, and if any one of them is false, they are all false.